# JQ not being recognized by AppleScript

Tags: macos, terminal, applescript, homebrew

I am running Homebrew on El Capitan, and have ansiweather installed. I am writing an AppleScript program to run the ansiweather command, and speak the contents. When I attempt running the ansiweather command from AppleScript, I get an error (69) stating it could not find JQ binary. However, when I run ansiweather from terminal it works perfectly. Any help?

Comment: Please share your code.

Answer (score 0):

Where you call **ansiweather** in your Applescript, be sure to use the full path like this:

```
/usr/local/bin/ansiweather
```

... because **homebrew** installs programs to that location.

So, here is an example:

```
osascript -e 'do shell script "ansiweather -l cheltenham"'
Current weather in Cheltenham => 17 °C ☁ - Wind => 10.3 m/s NW - Humidity => 59 % - Pressure => 1014 hPa
```

If you are invoking `jq` as well, you may need to set a different PATH if that isn't in `/usr/local/bin`. So, first, find where `jq` is with:

```
type jq
jq is /usr/local/bin/jq
```

then do this to add the above location into your PATH:

```
osascript -e 'do shell script "export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin; ansiweather -l cheltenham"'
```